# Accessing Session after upgrade to .net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, session, master-pages

I am having problems accesing the session after upgrading a web project to .net 4.5

firstly, I had a functional .net 3.5 web forms project which I upgraded to .net 4.5 on my dev machine. This compiled and worked well locally

Secondly I modified the application pools on my dev iis server to use .net 4.0 in preparation for running the new code deployment

Finally I deployed my upgraded project to the dev web server.

The problem is that I am getting an error straight away where I am being told I need to enable session state to access the session variables.

Background:

I have a master page which checks for the existance of a session variable. I have put this code in the page_init event of the master page to ensure it runs before the page_load of the content pages etc.

This technique worked fine under .net 3.5 and works well under 4.5 on the local dev machine. But does not work on the iis server.

I have followed various threads telling me to set enablesessionstate=true in the config all to no avail.

Could it be that there is either a problem with .net sites runnning .net 4.5 on iis with regards to sessions, or am I missing something more obvious.

Please help as this is very frustrating

Comment: Are you using in proc or state server session? Might have to be explicit in web.config about choice.  I'm  pretty certain it'd default to in proc, but could be wrong.  Saying that you'd prob be gettimg more fundamental errors

Comment: Can you show us what you have configured in system.web -> sessionState? There is a property called "mode" where you can set the sessionstate mode (it's an enum). Make sure that it is not set to "Off".

Comment: I am not at work today(back tomorrow) but Session is enabled on iis and set to (inproc) all is as it should be, in fact as a diagnostic, I configured a small standalone project using a simple session variable to prove that sessions were enabled. and this worked, So I believe the problem must either be with :

using sessions in master pages in .net 4.5?? ( a bug/ difference I am not aware of)
Where in the page lifecycle I am using the session on the master page (currently page_init)
Something else???
Sessions work, in a simple site, but not on my deployed site.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what was causing this? I have fixed the problem by creating a brand new .net 4.5 project and importing assets / pages from my preexisting site. Remarkably doing it this way caused no issue with the session after deployment to the web server, Very odd indeed. I can only assume that the project upgrade process that I initially used left some odd configuration in place which upset the server ??? Anyhow, have invested enough time in this now, thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what was causing this?

I have fixed the problem by creating a brand new .net 4.5 project and importing assets / pages from my preexisting site.

Remarkably doing it this way caused no issue with the session after deployment to the web server, Very odd indeed. I can only assume that the project upgrade process that I initially used left some odd configuration in place which upset the server ???

Anyhow, have invested enough time in this now, thanks for taking the time to comment.